# Individual builddir not working in Sphinx

Tags: internationalization, python-sphinx

i'm working on a Mac and use Sphinx 1.6.3 to build a documentation for my software.

Recently I tried the Internationalization feature, which works quite well.

But now I wanted to export the different language into different folders:

```
doc/de
doc/en
doc/fr
```

According to the docs, its simple:

```
$ sphinx-build -b html sourcedir builddir
```

http://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/usage/quickstart.html#running-the-build

So I tried this:

```
make -e SPHINXOPTS="-D language='en'" -b html /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/sakkadentrainer/doc/ /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/sakkadentrainer/doc/_build/html/en/
```

Which gives gives me the strange error:

> Error: source directory and destination directory are same.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score -1):

Issue solved. I had to use sphinx-build and not make

```
sphinx-build -b html /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/sakkadentrainer/doc/ /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/sakkadentrainer/doc_en/
```